# Can't query select data when my date is filled

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database structure like this:

[image]

and I want to check room type that available at a specific date, so I run this query.

```
SELECT type.type_name, orders_details.access_date 
FROM type 
LEFT JOIN rooms ON type.type_id = rooms.room_id
LEFT JOIN orders_details ON rooms.room_id = orders_details.room_id 
                         AND orders_details.access_date BETWEEN "2023-01-19" AND "2023-01-21" 
WHERE orders_details.access_date IS NULL 
GROUP BY type.type_name
```

I have several `rooms` for one `type` of `rooms`. I have 3 rooms that have same type id. When one of those `rooms` in same `type` is booked, and I run the query, the `type` is not showing.

How can I still query `type` even one `rooms` on of the type is still available?

Answer (score 0):

This part matching type_id with room_id looks illogical.

```
LEFT JOIN rooms ON type.type_id = rooms.room_id
```